# Data not formatted to date properly in d3

Tags: d3.js

This is probably very simple but I cant seem to get it to work. I am working with a scatterplot in d3 and the x axis is years. I cant seem to parse it into the correct format. So at the moment the years look like: `1,999 2,000 2,002` instead of `1999 2000 2002`.  Input is coming from a database. Here is the relevant code:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y")

var YearFn = function(d) {return parseDate.parse(d.YEAR) ;}; // THIS IS THE PART THAT THROWS AN ERROR

var Num_citationsFn = function(d) {return d.counter;};

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");    

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

d3.json("connection4.php", function(error,dataJson) {
allData = [];

dataJson.forEach(function(d) {
    var year = d.YEAR.toString().replace(",","");
    d.YEAR = parseDate(year);  
    d.counter = parseInt(d.counter);
    d.type = "In_library";

    allData.push(d);
    })

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(allData)

    circles.transition()
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(Num_citationsFn(d))})

    circles.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(Num_citationsFn(d))})
        .style("fill","blue")
}
```

This code throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: n.getFullYear is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
d3.json("connection4.php", function(error,dataJson) {
    var year = d.YEAR.toString().replace(",",""); //replace commas with blank
    d.YEAR = parseDate(year); //now parse the year string
    d.counter = parseInt(d.counter);//make the string a integer number
}
```

Comment: ok in the code you have pasted i dont see where the circles are made :) the above code doesn't seem to have any error

Comment: sorry for confusion and lack of necessary code, if you wouldnt mind seeing my editted question again you might be able to assist me further I really appreciate it! @Cyril

Comment: can you remove this line `circles.transition()
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(Num_citationsFn(d))})` and see if you get errors

Comment: after the for loop where you create  data set the domain `x.domain(d3.extent(allData, function(d) { return (d.YEAR); }))`
and for y as well
`y.domain(d3.extent(allData, function(d) { return (d.counter); }))`

Comment: in `circles.enter() ... .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})`
make it `circles.enter() ... .attr("cx", function(d) {return x((d))})`

Comment: the code works once I dont mess with formatting the year.. so I was just wondering how to manipulate the function that returns the x value of a circle `var YearFn = function(d) {return parseDate.parse(d.YEAR) ;};` so that it formats the year correctly.. am I making sense or am I off track.. @Cyril

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106092/discussion-between-cyril-and-paul-smith).

Comment: see you have already formatted the year before you push in the allData array so why are you doing it again here var YearFn = function(d) {return parseDate.parse(d.YEAR) ;}